# How to add downloadable products in opencart 2.0.1.1?

Tags: opencart2.x

I have tried to add some musics in my site which is free download products...

In admin->catalog->downloads (Uploaded Music files)

And in admin->catalog->products (Edit product) & link-> (added download file)

But it not shown in the Site it shows add to cart behaves like other products..

Comment: Bro
Download is only available after the order is completed.
So once the order status is complete, 
customer can login in to their profile and download file form download section

Answer (score 1):

you have to edit three pages(model, controller, template), After adding download file from admin in product

> Add this In opencart2\catalog\controller\product\product.php
>
> inside index() function or after line 159

```
$download_m = $this->model_catalog_product->download_m($product_id);
    if(!empty($download_m)){
    $data['download_m'] = $this->url->link('account/download/download', 'download_id=' . $download_m['download_id'], 'SSL');}
```

> Add this in opencart2\catalog\model\catalog\product.php
>   in this  class ModelCatalogProduct extends Model {

```
public function download_m($product_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'";
    if ($query->num_rows) {
      return array(
        'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],        
        'download_id'      => $query->row['download_id']
      );
    } 
  }
```

> At last Add in
>   opencart2\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl
>
> After < h1>< ?php echo $heading_title; ?> or line 138

```
<?php if(!empty($download_m)){ ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $download_m; ?>">download here</a></li>
          <?php } ?>
```

[image]